# Adding proxy with username and password authentication on Selenium Javascript wont work

Tags: javascript, selenium, proxy, selenium-chromedriver

when i try to add proxy to my program it doesnt work with username and password authentication I just get error saying website cant be reached but when I remove username and password proxy login pops up and when I enter it everything works okey.

````
const { Builder } = require('selenium-webdriver')

const chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome')

const PROXY = "username:password@ip:port"

const option = new chrome.Options().addArguments(\--proxy-server=http://${PROXY}`)`

const driver = new Builder().forBrowser('chrome').setChromeOptions(option).build()

driver.get('http://httpbin.org/ip')
.then(() => console.log('DONE'))```
````

Comment: As you are doing **End-To-End tests** here, I would suggest keeping it this way. Make the system login via your interface instead of implicitly sending the log in detail (which would be part of your **Integration testing** process).

Comment: @PatriceThimothee So you are saying when i get login pop up i should enter it there (Thru selenium)?

Comment: If you can, yes, end-to-End tests are meant to mimic as close as possible users' actions. When you do this, you have a greater chance of catching any eventual unexpected behaviour. Testing the log-in via proxy is best suited for the Integration test process. Nevertheless, it's up to you.